# How to find the value of column on the basis of matching column from two files?

Tags: unix, join, awk

file 1 : emp.txt

```
7839|KING|PRESIDENT||17-Nov-81|5000||10
7698|BLAKE|MANAGER|7839|01-May-81|2850||30
7782|CLARK|MANAGER|7839|09-Jun-81|2450||10
7566|JONES|MANAGER|7839|02-Apr-81|2975||20
7788|SCOTT|ANALYST|7566|19-Apr-87|3000||20
7902|FORD|ANALYST|7566|03-Dec-81|3000||20
7369|SMITH|CLERK|7902|17-Dec-80|800||20
7499|ALLEN|SALESMAN|7698|20-Feb-81|1600|300|30
7521|WARD|SALESMAN|7698|22-Feb-81|1250|500|30
7654|MARTIN|SALESMAN|7698|28-Sep-81|1250|1400|30
```

file 2 : dept.txt

```
  10|ACCOUNTING|NEW YORK
  20|RESEARCH|DALLAS
  30|SALES|CHICAGO
  40|OPERATIONS|BOSTON
```

I want to print below output :

```
7839|KING|PRESIDENT||17-Nov-81|5000||10|NEW YORK
7698|BLAKE|MANAGER|7839|01-May-81|2850||30|CHICAGO
7782|CLARK|MANAGER|7839|09-Jun-81|2450||10|NEW YORK
7566|JONES|MANAGER|7839|02-Apr-81|2975||20|DALLAS
7788|SCOTT|ANALYST|7566|19-Apr-87|3000||20|DALLAS
7902|FORD|ANALYST|7566|03-Dec-81|3000||20|DALLAS
7369|SMITH|CLERK|7902|17-Dec-80|800||20|DALLAS
7499|ALLEN|SALESMAN|7698|20-Feb-81|1600|300|30|CHICAGO
7521|WARD|SALESMAN|7698|22-Feb-81|1250|500|30|CHICAGO
7654|MARTIN|SALESMAN|7698|28-Sep-81|1250|1400|30|CHICAGO
```

I tried below awk statement, but it is not printing anything -

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR {val[$1]=$3; next} $8 in val {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,val[$1]}' OFS="|"   dept.txt emp.txt
```

Any Suggestion ??

Comment: didn't you forget `-F\|` ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, i just noticed that i have missed field seperator but i tried with that too but still no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there are two spaces in front of the matching column. Since you are using '|' as your field separator then each row of the second file is divided as follows.(Using the first row as example.)

```
  10|ACCOUNTING|NEW YORK

$1="  10"
$2="ACCOUNTING"
$3="NEW YORK"
```

So you are mapping `Accounting` with `"  10"` rather than `"10"`. Thats why you don't get any match in the second file. (Assuming you wanted to use val[$8] rather than val[$1] in the second print command).

Do the following. This will fix your problem.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR {sub("  ","",$1);val[$1]=$3; next;} $8 in val {print $1,$2
,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,val[$8]}' OFS="|"   dept.txt emp.txt
```

Output:

```
7839|KING|PRESIDENT||17-Nov-81|5000||10|NEW YORK
7698|BLAKE|MANAGER|7839|01-May-81|2850||30|CHICAGO
7782|CLARK|MANAGER|7839|09-Jun-81|2450||10|NEW YORK
7566|JONES|MANAGER|7839|02-Apr-81|2975||20|DALLAS
7788|SCOTT|ANALYST|7566|19-Apr-87|3000||20|DALLAS
7902|FORD|ANALYST|7566|03-Dec-81|3000||20|DALLAS
7369|SMITH|CLERK|7902|17-Dec-80|800||20|DALLAS
7499|ALLEN|SALESMAN|7698|20-Feb-81|1600|300|30|CHICAGO
7521|WARD|SALESMAN|7698|22-Feb-81|1250|500|30|CHICAGO
7654|MARTIN|SALESMAN|7698|28-Sep-81|1250|1400|30|CHICAGO
```

Comment: Verified. Looks like it was a formatting issue that there is some space in the beginning of line in dept.txt file but that brings sub function into picture that's a learning for me.

Comment: If ONLY there was some briefer way to write `print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8` for a record with 8 fields...  (hint: `$0`).

Answer (score 2):

Use `$NF`, which is the value of the last field:

```
➜ awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
    NR==FNR { location[$1] = $NF; next }
    { print (location[$NF] ? $0 OFS location[$NF] : $0) }
' dept.txt emp.txt
7839|KING|PRESIDENT||17-Nov-81|5000||10|NEW YORK
7698|BLAKE|MANAGER|7839|01-May-81|2850||30|CHICAGO
7782|CLARK|MANAGER|7839|09-Jun-81|2450||10|NEW YORK
7566|JONES|MANAGER|7839|02-Apr-81|2975||20|DALLAS
7788|SCOTT|ANALYST|7566|19-Apr-87|3000||20|DALLAS
7902|FORD|ANALYST|7566|03-Dec-81|3000||20|DALLAS
7369|SMITH|CLERK|7902|17-Dec-80|800||20|DALLAS
7499|ALLEN|SALESMAN|7698|20-Feb-81|1600|300|30|CHICAGO
7521|WARD|SALESMAN|7698|22-Feb-81|1250|500|30|CHICAGO
7654|MARTIN|SALESMAN|7698|28-Sep-81|1250|1400|30|CHICAGO
```

This assumes you still want the entire line regardless if the dept city index exists. If not then please update your question to reflect common use cases and expected output.

Comment: It works fine in this case but it will work like right outer join, let say if i will remove the record 10 from the dept.txt file it will print all the records from emp.txt file without location detail in last column. If i want to join only on the matched column then we need to modify the print statement like below -
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" } NR==FNR { location[$1] = $NF; next } $8 in location {print $0, location[$NF]}' dept.txt emp.txt
Not sure how to do that using ternary Operator. Let me know your suggestion.

Comment: right. just a tweak to avoid having to specify the common part of the print (`$0`) twice and make the test more robust: `print $0 ($NF in location ? OFS location[$NF] : "")`

Answer (score 1):

In your code line, you should call the hash by the column that has the id where you hashed each value, in your case, column 8 is the one that stores the common id for the file you want to print the info out.

```
awk -F\| 'NR==FNR {val[$1]=$3; next} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, val[$8]};' OFS="|"  dept.txt emp.txt
```