# How To Grep 2 Files With Regex To Find Match At End Of Line

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

I have the following two files:

`full-domains.txt` contains:

```
example1.com
example2.net
example3.org
example4.info
example5.co
```

`extensions.txt` contains:

```
net
org
co
```

I would like to loop the extensions into a grep command that will match only lines that end with the pattern in the extension file.

I'm thinking it's something like: `grep -Ff extensions.txt full-domains.txt` but I'm not sure where to add the syntax to make it match at the end of line with `$`.

The output should be:

```
example2.net
example3.org
example5.co
```

Any positive input is highly appreciated. I should add that I'm open to other solutions as well besides `grep`.

Comment: Add it in each line of extensions.txt and remove -F. Another less reliable option is to make use of `-w` switch to restrict the match to word boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly a job for awk:

```
$ awk -F'.' 'NR==FNR{exts[$0]; next} $NF in exts' extensions.txt full-domains.txt
example2.net
example3.org
example5.co
```

Comment: Hey Ed, this works for me! Thanks for the quick help. If you could provide a little explanation on the `awk` command, I would appreciate the knowledge. Thanks again.

Comment: I suspect you already know what it does since it's very basic and an extremely common awk idiom. What do you think it does and I'll be happy to correct you if you're wrong?

Comment: Okay, I'll probably make a fool of myself, but I'll try...NR=FNR sets a field to match. exts becomes a variable that looks for the field [$0] at the end of the line and next means print that. Then, NF prints all the matches in exts? Like I said, I'm really not good with awk. Just know its purpose and it's good for separating fields and manipulating text files.

Comment: The code doesn't say `NR=FNR`, it says `NR==FNR`. Note the double equals for comparison rather than assignment. NR increases across all files, FNR increases per file so that comparison is only tru for the first file read. `exts[$0]` stores the current record (`$0`) as an index of the array `exts[]`. `$NF in exts` is true when the last `.`-separated field in the current record (`$NF`) exists in the array `exts[]`. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you think you might do any more text manipulation for the rest of your life as you NEED to know awk for that

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the explanation. I actually followed that. Yea, I think I'm going to have to really learn `awk` properly. I've been doing too much with `sed` and `grep` when `awk` would be better. Thanks for the reference. Please upvote the question if you would like. Thanks again for the help Ed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use xargs to do multiple grep searches.

```
$ xargs -a extensions.txt -L1 -I{} grep "{}$" full-domains.txt
example2.net
example3.org
example5.co
```

xargs arguments:

- `-a extensions.txt` - read input from file
- `-L1` - line by line
- `-I{}` - replace `{}` from the command
- `grep "{}$"` - command to be executed for each extension

Answer (score 1):

You can try below solution -

```
vipin@kali:~$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$NF;next;} $2 in a {print $1,a[$NF]}' extensions.txt full-domains.txt
example2.net
example3.org
example5.co
```

Comment: Other than extraneous code, what is that adding compared to [the solution I posted earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40348559/1745001) and which the OP has already accepted?

Comment: I learnt few weeks back about how to  join two files using awk, I was trying to answer from what I learned few weeks back. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39941450/6404949

Comment: That's fine but there's no point re-posting an existing answer, especially if you're just adding a bunch of unnecessary code to it.